# (Python) How to sort lines of text file according to characters?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a text file where I put user information, like name, age etc. The file has to be sorted by age.

How I do that? I have the information of a user in one line, different kind of information separated by a space, and I have made the program so that age (for example) is in a block of 3: if the age is 5, there is 2 spaces and then string "5". Or if the age is 110, there is no spaces, just the string "110". The age is the first information in line so I just have to get the lines sorted by age.

Comment: Please show us a short sample of the input file.

Comment: It would be great if you could edit your question so your anticipated input and output were more clear than prose explanations, and added some code you have tried to implement already!

Comment: Seems like [`sort -k 3n textfile > newtextfile`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_%28Unix%29) would do the trick in unix ...

Comment: I would suggest not using spaces for separating data, use a unique character such as **,**

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
result = []

for line in open(fileName).readlines():
  line = line.strip()
  age = line[0:3] #This will get the first 3 characters of the line
  age = int(age)

  thisLine = {"age":age, "line":line}
  result.append(thisLine)

sortedList = sorted(result, key=lambda k: k["age"])
```

Basically you read in every line

-Strip off ending carriage returns and what not

-grab the 3 three characters (which will be your age)

-cast those to an Integer

-pop them into a dictionary/hashmap

-pop that into an array

-sort the array by the age attribute of the hashmap

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a task for a modified HistogramSort. It will work with variable line lengths (optional), provided random access writes are allowed. Very efficient and can work with huge files. It sorts stably.

Initialize 120 integer counters as 0.

Read the whole file line by line, getting the age value and the line length.

Take the line length and add it to the counter for Age+1.

After this first pass, every counter will tell you the space (number of characters) required for all lines of a given age.

Compute the prefix sum of the counters; this will tell you where the lines of a given age will start when sorted. The last counter gives you the total file size.

Then in a second pass, read line by line, copy every line to a new file, where it belongs (given the Age value) and update the corresponding counter.

[When the lifetime expectation of mankind increases, adjust the constant 120.]